JMeter Samplers getting skipped for no apparent reason
Wondering if anyone has seen this before as I don't understand how application changes could be triggering this pattern I'm seeing in JMeter.  All they're doing is updating packages on their angular application. They deploy it, I have this problem.  They roll it back, the problem goes away.
I have a script that checks the status of a data element, does something, then gets the status again before proceeding.
Whenever they deploy their changes, the call will only execute once - meaning the recheck of status does not occur.  The simple controller has other things in it (a debug sampler) that DOES execute, but NOT the sampler.
Does anyone have suggestions on what I can try?
evidence of sampler skip in loop
I have tried a ton of things, usually I can figure it out or find suggestions on things to try, but completely dumbfounded out application code is changing the behavior of how jmeter is behaving.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here.

There is always an "apparent" reason and the reason can be figured out from jmeter.log file.
If the log file doesn't contain anything meaningful - increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level, this way you will be able to see requests, responses, JMeter Variables values, any errors, etc.
One of the most common reasons for "skipping" the Sampler is having HTTP Cache Manager enabled, it simulates browser's cache and simply doesn't fire a request if the content hasn't changed since last request.
Going forward consider providing a minimal reproducible example as we cannot give you a comprehensive answer looking at a partial screenshot.
